# Sliding divs in css3 and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a web project where I want to have a row of images at the top of the page, but all of the images will be blurred out except for one.

What I was thinking was a div that overlays each image with a background colour of white and the opacity set to something like 0.5 with one of the images being completely visible.

There will be two buttons, previous and next and when one of these buttons are pressed the clear div will slide over the next image to reveal that image and the previous image will have been blurred like mentioned above.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do achieve this..

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please share some code you have tried yourself, and we'll be happy to offer suggestions on what might be wrong with it.

Comment: Could you show the screenshot of the effect you want to achieve? Or share the codes you have right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a little test, did you mean something like that?
To make them actually blurred out isn't as easy though. But it's a starting point i think.

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/2MExB/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="c"><ul>
<li><img height="100" src="..."/></li>
<li><img height="100" src="..."/></li>
<li><img height="100" src="..."/></li>
</ul><div id="m" ></div></div>
<br/>
<button>prev</button><button>next</button>​
```

**CSS:**

```
li{
 float:left;   
}

#c{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;    
}
#m{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    border:0 solid white;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;   
    opacity:.8;
}​
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    var current = 0;
    $('button').click(function(ev) {
        current += 1 * ($(this).text() == 'next' ? 1 : -1);
        show();
        ev.preventDefault();
    });

    function show() {
        var c = $('ul li').length;
        current = current < 0 ? c - 1 : (current > c - 1 ? 0 : current);
        var $t = $('ul li:eq(' + current + ')');
        var l = $t.position().left;
        var w = $t.width();
        var cw = $('#c').width();
        $('#m').stop().animate({
            'width': w,
            'border-width': '0 ' + (cw - l - w) + 'px 0 ' + l + 'px'
        }, 300);
    }
    show();
});​
```

Comment: Wow, that's excellent that is pretty much exactly what I was after, probably blurred wasn't the right choice of words couldn't think of a better one though. Thanks again much appreciated